# I need some help in my html page

Tags: javascript, jquery, apex

Is there a way to know if the user just opened the page? I got a textbox in my app that will retain its value even if the page was refreshed or submitted. What I want to do is to remove the content of the box when the user just accessed the page because what's happening right now is that whenever I close and rerun the page, the value of the textbox before I closed it is still there. Can you help me out?

Comment: Do you meant [local storage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/Guide/API/DOM/Storage)?

Comment: You can add this script in document.ready function. $("input[type=text]").val("");

Comment: add `value=""` in your `<input>` tag

Comment: Yes @Manoj but can you tell me how to do it on my case? Lets say I have a unique cookie called 'a'. When the user is going to run the page, a javascript function is going to check for cookie 'a'. If 'a' is not found then that means that the user have just visited the page. Cookie 'a' will not be removed even if the user submitted or refreshed the page. Cookie 'a' will only be removed once he left the page.

Comment: Post the code that you have so that you can get better help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[localStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/Guide/API/DOM/Storage) does it for you:

```
var element = $("input[type='text']");
var message = "This is the first time !";

if (localStorage.getItem("onlyOnce")) {
    element.val(""); // clear value
}
else {
    localStorage.setItem("onlyOnce", true);
    element.val(message);
    alert(message);
}
```

You can use together with the above:

```
$(window).on("beforeunload", function() { 
    localStorage.removeItem("onlyOnce");
});
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score -1):

You can add this script in document.ready function.

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
$("input[type=text]").val("");
});
</script>
```

Comment: But I only need to remove the contents of the textbox once the user left the site @Power Star, not on every page submit or page refresh..

Comment: Then please use the id of text box to remove particular thing.

Comment: Or you can include value attribute inside text box.  <input type="text" value="" />

Comment: it is still there @Power Star. I have closed the page then reopened it but the value is still there. I've got an idea. How about storing a cookie in the user's browser the first time it is loaded(I dont know how to do this though)? Then by the time the user closes the page, that cookie will be removed(but not on page refresh or submit). That cookie will be the basis of my javascript code whether it's going to remove the content of the textbox or not.

Comment: Then you have to remove cookie at the time of closing page. How do you find page is closed. If possible then please paste your code.

Comment: I don't know yet @Power Star. It's only an idea. Maybe you can teach me how to find out when the page is closed?